# coffeescript accessing instance variable

Tags: class, scope, coffeescript, instance

im somewhat new to js or coffeescript and i cant figure out what is wrong with my script.

```
class Token

  fetching_token = $.Deferred()
  assigning_token = $.Deferred()

  constructor: ->
    @token = null
    @got_token = $.Deferred()    

  fetch = ->
    fetching_token.resolve({"access_token": '12355'})

  assign_token = (data) =>
    console.log "TOKEN (instance var): " + @token #undefined? 
    @token = data.access_token
    assigning_token.resolve()

  get_token: ->
    fetch()
    $.when(fetching_token).done (data) =>
      assign_token(data)
    $.when(assigning_token).done =>
      @got_token.resolve()
    undefined


t = new Token
t.get_token()

$.when(t.got_token).done ->
  console.log "FETCHED TOKEN: " + t.token #gives null
```

Im trying to expose following interface on instance of object: *token*, *got_token*, *get_token*.
For some reason the *@token* in *assign_token* is *undefined*. I tried some combinations with *fat arrow* but couldnt make it to work.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple (private) function, not a method:

```
f = (arg) -> ...
```

This is a private function that is bound to the class:

```
f = (arg) => ...
```

The `=>` binds the function to whatever `@` (AKA `this`) is when the function is defined. When you say this:

```
class C
    f = (arg) => ...
```

`@` is the class `C` when `f` is being parsed so `f` is sort of a private class method.

The important thing is that when you say this:

```
assign_token = (data) =>
  #...
```

`@` inside `assign_token` will not be an instance of `Token`, it will actually be `Token` itself. Your `@token` is an instance variable on *instances* of `Token` so of course it isn't defined when you don't have an instance of `Token` in `@`.

You have a couple options:

1. Make `assign_token` an instance method. This makes `assign_token` publicly accessible.
2. Force the `@` issue using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). This keeps `assign_token` private but more cumbersome to call.

The first option looks like this:

```
assign_token: (data) ->
    # Same stuff you already have
```

The second on is (mostly) done when you call `assign_token`:

```
assign_token = (data) ->
    # Same stuff you already have

get_token: ->
  fetch()
  $.when(fetching_token).done (data) =>
    assign_token.call(@, data)
  #...
```

Note the skinny arrow (`->`) when defining `assign_token`, that gives you a simple function so that you can set the desired `@` when you call it with the function's `call` method.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected now. I wasnt aware of _call_, I will keep it in mind.